# Handling Differences in Capability Between Service Layer Versions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

We have different clients running different versions of our software's service layer. Newer service components have some capabilities that the older ones don't have. We are working on a new presentation layer that we wish to offer to all of our clients. It should work for clients with the older services, but provide access to the newer capabilities should the client be running the latest services layer.

I'd like to avoid littering the code with if statements about every possible feature difference, especially as we will keep adding and supporting new capabilities in the service layer. What, if any, design pattern would you suggest to deal with this difference in capability most cleanly?

Answer (score 1):

If the differences are mostly in the view, partial views and replacing RenderPartial with a custom extension RenderPartialIfSupported should keep the code fairly clean. Arrange the views in version folders and you shouldn't need to specify the required version directly in the main view code.

If the version differences are easily linked to actions, an action filter attribute is a good approach - then you can just add [RequireVersion(1.1)] to each action that isn't universally supported.

You can also combine these with a custom version of ActionLink that finds the relevant action and its RequireVersion Attribute and renders nothing if the action is unsupported.

Comment: Upvoting for nice suggestions. I am hoping for a solution where the views and controllers don't know anything about version numbers, just different repository capabilities. We inject repository dependencies into our controllers, so we can leave it to our DI framework to know which version we're hitting.

Comment: The same approach will work using a required interface or property name instead of the version number. If you need to check multiple capabilities you'll need to go with the filter attribute method though. For the views you can set up something between RenderAction and RenderPartial - it calls an action method so that it can check the filter attributes, but the model is passed as a parameter rather than being generated by the action.